# How to define form select values via model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, model, scaffolding

I created a simple model called Categories, which is connected to Platforms model.

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :url, :country, :categories
   belongs_to  :category
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :platforms
end
```

I also successfully have form for creating new Platforms :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@platform) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :url %>
    <%= f.input :country %>
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, @categories, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately ,since model Category is new, dropdown currently has only 1 value "Please selected". How do I add new values to this select, preferably via the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with simple_form, you can automatically generate the drop-down using

```
<%= f.association :category %>
```

This will automatically populate the list with categories from the database. See the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for more tips.

EDIT:
Categories simply have to be added separately. You can either manually seed your database with categories with the db/seeds.rb script or through the rails console. Or you can allow users to add categories through a separate form and controller.

For example, to create a few categories in the console, run `rails c` from the command line and run `Category.create!(name: "Name")` for a few names.

Comment: I know that, but how do I add categories to the categories list in the database, it is empty at the moment, since I have nowhere defined any.

Comment: Please see edit. Are you looking for the ability to create categories while adding platforms within the same form?

Comment: I think console is enaught, if you could also tell me how to add a new form for this, it could also be helpful for other people who view this tread.

Comment: If you want to create categories in a separate form, you'd just do exactly what you did here with the platform form.

Answer (score 0):

In your `new` action of PlatformsController, add `@categories = Category.all` , so you will have all category.

Comment: Thats exactly how its set up at the moment, but I do not know how to add new categories to the categories list. (Basically how do I add them to database? )

Comment: Okey, if you want to create new category with platform at the same time, you can use [nested form](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).